# Error occurred. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'messageId')

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

First time using nodemailer but am having trouble with sending mail. Every time I try to send mail to ethereal mail it fails to send the mail, only to say that it 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mesageId')'. Below, are my code and logs. Thanks!

**Console**

```
    [2022-10-18 14:08:55] DEBUG Creating transport: nodemailer (6.8.0; +https://nodemailer.com/; SMTP/6.8.0[client:6.8.0])
    [2022-10-18 14:08:55] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.8.0[client:6.8.0]
    Error occurred. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'messageId')
    ::1 - - [18/Oct/2022:14:08:55 +0000] "POST /posts HTTP/1.1" 200 10 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    [2022-10-18 14:08:55] DEBUG [AO7ADWBuDE] Resolved smtp.ethereal.email as 54.36.85.113 [cache miss]
```

**utils/nodemailer.js**

```
export async function sendMail(username, address, text) {
  // Create a SMTP transporter object
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: 'diego.marks28@ethereal.email',
      pass: 'YvQ1FS9g8Ut8qWE1Jz',
    },
    debug: true,
    logger: true,
  });
  // transporter.verify((err, success) => {
  //   if (err) console.error(err);
  //   console.log('Your config is correct');
  // });


  let message = {
    from: 'do_not_reply@northpole.com',
    to: 'santa@northpole.com',
    subject: 'New wish from a child has been requested!',
    html: `<p>Dear Santa Clause,<br>
        A child has sent his wish. Below are the details.<br>
        <ul>Username: ${username} </ul>
        <ul>Address: ${address}</ul>
        <ul>Wish: ${text}</ul>
        </p>`,
  };
  return transporter.sendMail(message, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(info);
  });

  // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account\
}
```

**server.js**

```
    app.post('/posts', async (request, response) => {
  const { username, address, text } = request.body;
  await addPost(username, address, text);

  try {
    const data = await sendMail(username, address, text);
    console.log('Message sent: %s', data.messageId);
    return response.json({
      username: username,
      address: address,
      text: text,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error occurred. ' + err.message);
    return response.send('error here');
  }
});
```

Comment: Where you are using ```messageId``` ? You have to give proper code.

Comment: @EMRANHOSSAIN it's on line 7 of server.js. However, that's actually not the issue. The problem I think is that server.js on line 5 where the sendMail is returned as undefined, but the logs don't display anything about my sendMail function.

Comment: So you just console the data. What gives in the console?

Comment: @EMRANHOSSAIN Ok, I figured it out. The first await function disrupts my sendMail(), and so removed my sendMail() to cronjob since I had to use it there regardless.